# Execute a command after each output line from ping command

Tags: command-line, osx, ping

I am trying to build a one-line command to monitor when my Internet connectivity drops.

I'd like it so that if I run `ping www.google.com` indefinitely (one ping per second), if the word "timeout" exists in an output line, another command runs, but the `ping` command continues to run indefinitely.

I'm running this on OS X, so the other command is `say fail` so I can audibly hear that there is a problem if I'm not looking at the terminal window.

If it can't be a one-line command, then a bash script would be fine.

I tried this:

`ping www.google.com | grep timeout ; say fail`

but that only executes the `say` command after the user manually terminates the `ping` command.

Then I tried this:

`if ping www.google.com | grep timeout ; then say fail ; fi`

But that never executes the `say` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the ping command that never exits.

You should make a loop that call `ping` for one test `-c 1`:

```
while [ true ] ; do if ping -c 1 www.google.com | grep timeout ; then say fail ; fi ; sleep 1 ; done
```

*edit*

- I wrote a `bash` while loop, may be you should adapt it to your shell program (It's been a long time I play with mac os X),
- I added some pause (one second) to prevent the loop to consume too much cpu...

Comment: Worked perfectly without any modifications needed in bash 3.2.57 on OS X.